# XPath to select text containing ® symbol?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

It seems XPath doesn't recognize the symbol ® when it appears in text in an HTML document.

```
.//*[contains(text(), '®')]

.//*[contains(text(), '&reg;')]

.//*[contains(text(), 'U+00AE')]

.//*[contains(text(), '&#174;')]
```

None of these return a result using inspector in chrome on a page that has multiple instances of ® on it.

Has anyone ever faced this problem? How can xpath locate a ® ?

Comment: Some related discussion... https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20736407/XML-Displaying-Trademark-Symbol.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
$x("//text()[contains(.,'®')]")
```

returns 7 text nodes containing `®` on this page (before I answered, that is).

Answer (score 0):

The Unicode code for this character is x2122, so if you want to use a numeric reference it should be `&#x2122;` or `&#8482;`.

The codes xAE and 174 are how Windows-1252 represents the character; that's totally irrelevant as far as XML and XPath are concerned.

I've no idea where you got the idea of writing U+00AE, that just seems to be wishful thinking.

Of course it's possible that the character is miscoded in the XML file. The encoding actually used for the character in the file needs to match the encoding declared in the XML declaration at the start of the file.

Comment: U+00AE is the unicode mapping, I was just trying anything at that point lol